# How to throw a 401 Unauthorized Exception in .NET (JWT Validate Token)?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, jwt

I have a .NET 4.5 API application. It's protected with OWIN/Oauth. I make a call with POSTMAN and fake the Bearer token, so i can test this case.
How to break the code execution after the `validateToken` function finds out that the JWT token has been manipulated/is not valid?

```
ClaimsPrincipal principal = handler.ValidateToken(protectedText, _validationParameters, out validToken);
```

This row gives back a SecurityTokenException. I catch the Exception like that:

```
catch (SecurityTokenException ex)
{
     var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Access Token is manipulated" };
     throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
}
```

After that the application execution continues and goes in the constructor of the ApiController I called through postman, which is protected with [Authorize], instead of giving me a HTTPResponse with 401 Unauthorized

P.S. Here is the code of the constructor in the ApiController

```
public class TicketController : ApiController
{
     private readonly TicketService _svcTicket;

     public TicketController()
     {
           try
           {
              _svcTicket = new TicketService(JwtFormat.AppContext);
           }
           catch (SecurityTokenException ex)
           {
                var msg = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { ReasonPhrase = "Access Token is manipulated" };
                    throw new HttpResponseException(msg);
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                throw ex;
           }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is caller of this function catching the HttpResponseException?

Comment: The caller is the tool POSTMAN. i edited my post and added the Api Controller constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it out:

```
public class TicketController : ApiController
{
 private readonly TicketService _svcTicket;

 public TicketController()
 {
       try
       {
          if(tokenIsManipulated) {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Access Token is manipulated")
                });
          }
        }
        catch(HttpResponseException)
        {
            throw;
        }
   }
}
```

There are 2 important things my code was missing before:

1. A new HttpResponseMessage object while throwing
2. An extra catch block for HttpResponseException's